# Text from webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from https://markets.cboe.com/europe/equities/market_share/index/all/  using Python

Specifically the figure for "Market Non-displayed volume total", I've tried several ways using BeautifulSoup but none seem to get me there.

any ideas?

Comment: please share what you have done so far and point out where it failed.

Comment: I can't find anything on that page that says "Market Non-displayed volume total"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest giving the pandas html reader a shot:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in all tables at this address as pandas dataframes
results = pd.read_html('https://markets.cboe.com/europe/equities/market_share/index/all')

# Grab the second table founds
df = results[1]
# Set the first column as the index
df = df.set_index(0)
# Switch columns and indexes
df = df.T
# Drop any columns that have no data in them
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
# Set the column under "Displayed Price Venues" as the index
df = df.set_index('Displayed Price Venues')
# Switch columns and indexes again
df = df.T

# Aesthetic. Don't like having an index name myself! 
del df.index.name

# Separate the three subtables from each other!  
displayed = df.iloc[0:18]
non_displayed = df.iloc[18:-1]
total = df.iloc[-1]
```

You can also do this in a more aggressively compact way (same code but without breaking the steps down):

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in all tables at this address as pandas dataframes
results = pd.read_html('https://markets.cboe.com/europe/equities/market_share/index/all')

# Do all the stuff above in one go
df = results[1].set_index(0).T.dropna(how='all',axis=1).set_index('Displayed Price Venues').T

# Aesthetic. Don't like having an index name myself! 
del df.index.name

# Separate the three subtables from each other!  
displayed = df.iloc[0:18]
non_displayed = df.iloc[18:-1]
total = df.iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `id` keep changing dynamically. Otherwise, I would have just used that but can't. Assuming that the Output value is what you're looking for, this should work, also as long as the content doesn't change or get shifted around.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://markets.cboe.com/europe/equities/market_share/index/all/'
page = requests.get(url)
html = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
total_volume = html.findAll('td', class_='idx_val')
print(total_volume[645].text)

Output:
€4,378,517,621
```